# Am I using malloc in a wrong way?

Tags: c

I used malloc to give some space to pointer.
First I wrote a line like below to give 4byte space for one integer.

```
int *minus = malloc(4);    // minus: 0x6a1590
```

and I used vscode debugging to see if it's done well.
result showed like "minus: 0x6a1590".

After that I gave char pointer a space.

```
char *str = malloc(2);    // str : 0x6a15d0 "\300>������������������������������"
```

I just gave str a 2byte space but there is lots of thing in str.

Why is this happening? I thought there should be two null character in str..

Comment: Are you initializing those two chars to anything?

Comment: That looks like the debugger trying to interpret variable as a string. Just ignore it since you have not initialised the string contents.

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but it would be more portable to write `int *minus = malloc(sizeof(int));`, in that it would still do the right thing even on platforms where `ints` are not 4 bytes long.

Comment: Note that the memory bytes returned by `malloc()` are *not* guaranteed to be all zeros.  If you want guaranteed all-zero buffers to be returned, you can use `calloc()` instead (or just call `memset()` on the returned bytes to zero them out yourself)

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize anything.  Compare with `calloc`.

Comment: Thank you all of you I will just ignore that value. And I didn't initialized it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Better still: `int *minus = malloc( sizeof *minus );` If the declaration as 'int*' were changed to 'double *minus = ...' for instance... Fewer maintenance points mean fewer unnoticed bugs. `:-)`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm not trying to correct you, but my OCD got me used to write pointers as `int* ptr` instead of `int *ptr`, to highlight that the pointer is the type, rather than the variable name :) I think that might be a good practice and help to learn how they works

Comment: @mikyll98 I just copied the questioner's syntax verbatim :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever tool you are looking at to view the contents of `str` is assuming that it points to a string. But it doesn't point to a string, it just points to the two bytes of memory that you allocated which have no particular contents. So the information you are seeing there is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

David Schwartz gave you the right answer. Your debugger is showing the garbage that it's finding in the memory location you are pointing to with the str pointer. Here are some tips to help you.

When you declare a char* (a pointer to a character) it's usually because you want to store a string of characters. In the C language strings are terminated with a '\0' character. This is called the null character.

Since you didn't initialize your string after allocating its memory, there is just random junk in the memory that was assigned to you. The debugger knows that your `str` variable is a `char*` so it starts reading and printing out memory interpreting each byte according to the [ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com). It's printing out characters (one for each byte) until it finds the null ('\0') a character.

To get a better result, change your code to the following:

```
char *str = malloc(2); 
*str = ' '; /* set the first byte to be a blank space character */
*(str+1) = '\0'; /* set the second byte to be null */
```

These additional two lines initialize the two bytes you've allocated to make them an empty (blank) string.

I'm gonna post some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAZFaacJMNRm3JIn3nNR1cQ) soon about strings and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Declaring `char *` does not define a string. Nothing in the C standard requires a `char *` to point to a string; it is entirely legitimate for `char *` to point to an array of `char` that is not a string. Arrays of characters must be null-terminated strings when used with certain routines of the C standard library, but they do not need to be strings generally.

Comment: The character with zero value is properly called a null character, using lowercase. Calling it a NULL character risks confusing it with the `NULL` macro, which is an entirely different thing for pointers. There is an ASCII designation for the null character that uses uppercase, but it is NUL, not NULL.

Comment: The `''` in `*str = '';` is not a valid character constant. Per C 2018 6.4.4.4 1, a character constant must contain at least one character.

Comment: "them an empty (blank) string." --> Hmmm. It really is not empty and this sounds a bit like an _empty_ string `""`, which is different.   Unclear why even call it an empty (blank) string.  BTW, good luck on your videos - so far good diction and clarity in the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask the debugger to print an `int *`, it prints the value of the pointer.

When you ask the debugger to print a `char *`, it prints the value of the character and also attempts to interpret the memory it points to as a character string. It does this because a `char *` is very often used to point to the first (or current, in some sense) character of a character string.

The memory provided by `malloc` is not guaranteed to be set to any particular value, zero or otherwise. When you print the `char *`, the additional output you see is due to the debugger displaying the characters it finds in memory, up to the first null character it finds. There is no additional output from printing the `int *` simply because the debugger does not attempt to display the contents of the memory that the `int *` points to.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because strings are null-terminated in C, and there is no zero-byte at the end of your 2-byte string. So it shows you all the bytes up until the first zero.

Plus, malloc is not guaranteed/required to return a block of memory filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` does not zero out the allocated memory.  If you want the memory to be zeroed out on allocation, use `calloc` instead:

```
char *str = calloc( 2, sizeof *str );
```

Strings are sequences of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  Formatted output routines like `printf` with the `%s` conversion specifier or `puts` are given a pointer to the first character of the string, and they'll write out successive characters until they see that terminator.  If you give those routines the starting address of a character array that *doesn't* contain a terminator, it will blast right past the end of that array and interpret the following bytes as characters until it sees a zero-valued byte.  Hence the garbage you saw.